# Регулярное выражение не находит многострочных совпадений

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt, qt5

Не могу понять где ошибся. Помогите, пожалуйста. Вот текст, который на самом деле содержит символы перехода на новую строку (я удалил их, чтобы не загромождать текст вопроса):

```
<div id="p0" class="productContainer" style="width: 195px; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 35px"><div class="title" style="font-size: 14px">AmazonBasics HDMI Input to D?</div><a href="#!product/1-B014I8UQJY"><div class="productBox colorTipContainer whiteDeals" id="pB0"><div class="productImageDiv"><div class="productImage"><img class="active " src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41-O%2BZoRjZL._SS180_.jpg" width="180px" height="180px"></div></div><div class="productSmallDescription" style="margin-left: 6px;"><span class="searchPrices"><div class="priceLegend productPriceTableSmall">Amazon: <span class="priceAmazon productPriceTableSmall" style="line-height: 13px;">?$ 6.59</span></div><div class="priceLegend productPriceTableSmall"><span class="priceAmazon productPriceTableSmall" style="line-height: 13px;">?</span></div><div class="priceLegend productPriceTableSmall"><span class="priceAmazon productPriceTableSmall" style="line-height: 13px;">?</span></div></span></div><span class="colorTip" style="width: 250px; top: -18px;"><span class="colorTipContent">AmazonBasics HDMI Input to DVI Output Adapter Cable - 6 Feet (Latest Standard)</span><span class="pointyTipShadow"></span><span class="pointyTip"></span></span></div></a></div><br><div style="clear: both;margin: 60px;text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/search?keywords=AmazonBasics%20HDMI%20Input%20to%20DVI%20Output%20Adapter%20Cable%20-%206%20Feet%20(Latest%20Standard)" class=".tabTrack">>?Continue your search on Amazon?<</a></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Использую QT код:

```
QString IS_TEST = "(?<=<div id=\"p0\" class=\"productContainer\").+(?=Continue your search on Amazon)";
QRegularExpression* re = new QRegularExpression(IS_TEST, QRegularExpression::MultilineOption);
QRegularExpressionMatch match = re->match(site);
if(match.hasMatch()) {
    qDebug() <<"НАШЛО";
}
```

Comment: Какой результат вы хотите получить? Приведите примеры подходщих строк и неподходящих. Разбор HTML лучше проводить специализированными парсерами, например, воспользуйтесь услугами [QXmlQuery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlquery.html). В С++ можно использовать т.н. сырые строки и не экранировать двойние кавычки внутри. `R"(... любой текст ...)"`

Comment: Я хочу получить все что между <div id="p0" class="productContainer"  и вот этим Continue your search on Amazon

Comment: "Разбор HTML лучше проводить специализированными парсерами," Может вы и правы просто ее изучить надо а с регулярками я работал.

Comment: сама регулярка вроде [правильная](https://regex101.com/r/LAnym7/1)

Comment: Да и код ваш у меня выдал "НАШЛО". Напишите пример кода который можно скомпилировать и воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: Я просто не весь код поставил. Причина почему регулярка не работала в наличии символа \n я воспользовался удалением \n с помощью replace и все заработало.

Comment: @MadokaMagica Кажется, всё что нужно - это заменить `QRegularExpression::MultilineOption` на `QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption`. Не надо трогать `\n`. И `.+` заменить на `.+?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените флаг `QRegularExpression::MultilineOption`, который изменяет поведение метасимволов `^` (начало строки) и `$` (конец строки), на [`QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html), который изменяет поведение точки (заставляет её находить знаки перевода строки/возврата каретки).

Также `.+` заменить на `.+?` для поиска ближайшего справа `Continue your search on Amazon`.

Кроме того, `(?<=a).+?(?=b)` эффективнее переписать как `a(.+?)b`, а потом вместо получить искомое значение через

```
QRegularExpression re("<div\\s+id=\"p0\"\\s+class=\"productContainer\"(.+?)Continue your search on Amazon", QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption);
QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(site);
if (match.hasMatch()) {
    QString day = match.captured(1); // Группа №1 содержит искомое значение
}
```

Comment: Да спс помогло правда не тут, но к этому вопросу тоже может считаться правильным ответом. QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption я еще не проверял, но  то потом